# Git file tracking after it was removed from index

Tags: git

I have the file `x.conf` that I wanted some time ago to keep in the project, but not have it tracked by git. I ran `git rm --cached` and it did exactly what I wanted. Now, I have some changes in that file that I want to commit, so I want git to track it again. I tried `git add x.conf` and `git add -f x.conf`, but neither worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it by renaming the file outside git, then adding it to git and renaming it to the old name inside git with the `git mv` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you removed the file from the index, since you wanted to ignore it.

But if you plainly proceeded to add the file to .gitignore, git should’ve explicitly warned you about this when you have tried to `git add` the file, in quite a self-explanatory way - exiting with a *fatal* error to boot.

There is a more subtle way though to ignore the file - you must have marked the file with `--assume-unchanged` (see [git help update-index](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html)) and forgot about it.

It it easy to check. In the directory where x.conf is located, run:

```
git ls-files -v -- x.conf
```

and if you see the file displayed with a lower-case prefix, then git thinks it is assumed to be unchanged <sup>1</sup>.

Fix it like this:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged x.conf
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> [The relevant setting in the source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/ls-files.c#L456).</sub>